# Self executing anonymous function not executing in Firefox (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I've got a testimonial plugin that rotates.  On a very basic level here is what it does:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5hJH/2/

For some reason the link above works in both FF and Chrome, but on my site (with some AJAX and animation) it doesn't work on FF.

Here's the site: http://simplicityabc.com/cms/.  The testimonials are down in the footer.

There are no console errors using Firebug and when I add an alert or console.log to the anonymous function in firefox it never fires.  It just seems that FF is ignoring that function altogether.

Comment: You forgot to declare "rotateSwitch" with `var`

Comment: it isn't a IFFY, it is a normal jQuery constructor call with a function as parameter

Comment: So you created a jsFiddle with code that IS working for you, and you need help with some other code that is not working?

Comment: Yeah, I was providing evidence that my script should be working fine. Nothing on the inside of my closure is being executed, but it executes in JsFiddle.

Comment: @Pointy - adding it doesn't seem to help :(

Comment: The jsfiddle script is significantly different from the script in the actual page. You need to keep building up the jsfiddle until you can replicate the failure, or else simply use the debugging tools in your browser to trace what's going on in the actual page.

Comment: In your "rotateSwitch" timer handler, for example, the variable "testimonials" is undefined.  Where is it supposed to get a value from?

Comment: Ah - get rid of the `var` in the ajax handler. That's making the outer "testimonials" variable to be hidden by that local one. Sometimes you need `var`, sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what else might be wrong (if anything), but here's a problem:

```
$.ivycat_ajax_do( { 'action' : 'get-testimonials', 'testimonial-dets' : $( '#testimonial-dets' ).val() }, function( resp ){
    var testimonials = $.parseJSON( resp );
});
```

That declaration of "testimonials" **inside** the ajax callback handler means that the response is parsed and assigned to a **local** variable (inside the handler) called "testimonials". The like-named variable in the outer context will therefore not be affected, and it will remain `undefined`.

Take away the `var` on that line and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
( function($){

    function change_testimonial(){
        $( '#generic-testimonial .content p' ).html( 'It greately affected my life!' );
        $( '#generic-testimonial footer cite' ).html( 'John Doe' );
        console.log("entering here normally")
    };
     rotateSwitch = function( ){
            play = setInterval(function( ){
            change_testimonial();
            }, 8000);
        };

        rotateSwitch(  );
} )(jQuery)
```

Comment: I tried it this way as well, but still doesn't execute anything in the function in FF. It does in jsFiddle, but not on my site.  No firebug console errors either.

Comment: There must be sth else messing with you js, ive test above code and my console.log shows as expected in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I probably shouldn't have even posted the jsFiddle example, it was more to show that it should work.  The jsFiddle example worked form the beginning, the one that doesn't work is the other link (simplicityabc.com/cms)